# PHP YII inject static HTML file inside view

Tags: php, yii, view

a newbie with php and with yii framework. 
Iam mixing YII with angular js on frontend and for that i need to inject a static html file (angular template) inside the YII view. So that they can directly be used from the $templateCache using the id.

Things i have tried are
1. `$this->render();` //inside view
2. `$this->renderFile();` //inside view

So basically my code is like this

```
<div class="container container-fluid" ng-app="shopsApp">
<!--angular templates-->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="shop-create.html">
  <?php $this->renderFile('/_partials/shop-create.html.php') ?>
</script>
```

The error that im getting is

```
require(/_partials/shop-create.html.php): failed to open stream: No such
file or directory
(C:\xampp\htdocs\freshmonk\yii\framework\web\CBaseController.php:130)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved this. SInce im new to PHP i was missing the `Yii->import` after doing an import of the required file. The problem ceased to exist.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that directory does not exist. I think the problem is path to your static html file. Try to use `$this->renderFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/_partials/shop-create.html.php')` instead. If did not work, try to remove `.php` extension from the end.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at render **Render Partial**. It is used to render a view but the key difference is that it does not apply a layout to the rendered result. It is thus mostly used in rendering a partial view, or an AJAX response.

How it works

It takes the alias given and converts it into a file path using all the local variables such as current running controllers and modules and alias definitions. It then pretty much just uses render file.

```
$this->renderPartial($view);
```

As for your case it would be something like this

```
$this->renderPartial('_partials/shop-create.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [renderPartial()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial);

And perhaps the parameter should be prepend with "//" like this

```
    $this->renderPartial('//layouts/templates/my_template');
```

The "//" is your `/themes/[theme_name]/views/`, or if you don't set the theme folder on your config file, it is located on `/protected/views/`